# Magento Quantity box with JQUERY on list.phtml

Tags: php, ajax, magento, jquery

I want to add a quantity box on magento's list.phtml.
Currently the code for the box is:

```
<div>
       <button type="button" style=" margin-left:185px; min-height:48px;"title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br /><br/>
       </div>
```

Now that works for adding just 1 product , but there is NO qty box.
how can i get that to work without reloading the page?

These are my scripts loaded on the bottom of that page.
http://pastebin.com/0bdey92h

Hope that somebody is here to rescue me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('button.btn-cart').parent().append('<input type="text" name="qty">');
```